# Is there an ObjC macro or function to get all the argument values received by a method?

Tags: objective-c, reflection, arguments

I know that `NSStringFromSelector(_cmd)` gives the name of the current method. I use that in a debugging macro to print what method I'm in. I would like to also get the method's arguments as strings so I can print them too. I'm thinking of something like `*argv[]` in C.

Is there any built-in facility for that?

Comment: Pretty sure there's not.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, c++ (and Objective-C) support va_list.
Do something like this:

```
- (void)do:(va_list)args
{
   // do something with all your args
}
```

And use it like this:

```
[self do:@"foo", @"bar"]
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to be a solution to the OP's problem, because it requires changing the method's definition and use.

Comment: This isn't really what the OP meant. Robert wanted to get a string containing the arguments for any method, not write a method that can take a variable number of arguments. Also, that isn't how you use a va_list. You use the varargs macros inside a variadic function to get the va_list. Declaring a function as taking a va_list means you are actually supposed to pass a va_list rather than multiple arguments.

Comment: Yep, sorry, got his question wrong.

Comment: Yes these comments are right. I'm the OP and what I was looking for was to get the names and values of the arguments to the current method without knowing their number or names in advance. I wanted to use that to make a general purpose debug macro. I've since learned that such an ability is a kind of holy grail that many seek but nobody finds.